# jquery validation plugin textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

Using the [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) in the event of a textarea failing validation - required - it is not being highlighted.  Looking for suggestions on how to make this happen.

Comment: Providing some code would help. Here's a very simple example of a required `textarea` working: http://jsfiddle.net/rjx5V/

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I just re-read your question and realized you're specifically talking about the highlighting... Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

in the CSS for the plugin, there's only:

```
input.error { border: 1px dotted red; }
```

it should be

```
input.error, textarea.error { border: 1px dotted red; }
```

The problem actually happens in the Demo website for the plugin.